# Flutter Firebase Dynamic Link is not working on new install

Tags: flutter, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I faced with problem of first run with query parameters after new install of app. I use flutter app and check for new links by this pease of code:

```
final PendingDynamicLinkData? initialLink =
    await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
```

And it works if I just click on link when app is closed or in tray (paused). So custom firebase scheme works in this scenario.

https://example.com/?route=season
and full link at firebase console:

> https://example.page.link/?link=https://example.com/?route%3Dseason&apn=***&isi=***&ibi=***

Sometimes due installing I get this log from firebase:

> my.custom.schema://google/link/?request_ip_version=IP_V6&match_message=No%20pre-install%20link%20matched%20for%20this%20device.

But I use the same link that works while app is installed. Note that I don't use "Skip the preview page" flag.

Flow with this link (when app is not installed):

1. click on link from email
2. see preview page "https://preview.page.link/example.page.link/season"
3. redirect to app store (after click on OPEN)
4. first open an App

Any help could be appreciated! Thank in advance.

Comment: see https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/1244